# How to perform decision tree lookup using mapreduce? I am looking for an optimized version

Tags: decision-tree

I have decision tree with millions of nodes, serialized on HDFS. Can any one please help me giving some pointer how to do better serialization so that I can perform search more efficiently on Hadoop using map reduce.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well in order to traverse your tree, you need the model to be loaded into memory. Once it is loaded it is pretty easy and fast to perform a traverse of an instance. You cant avoid storing  your model into hdfs, so in order to perform a better traverse, you need to do something better in your main memory. But as i said, a tree traverse is always super fast. Perhaps providing some more information about your problem would be nice. Your problem is having millions of new examples and predicting their label?